# creating a gem of a jruby app with jars as deps

Tags: rubygems, jruby

I saw a lot about putting gems in jars but not the other way around.

I have a Jruby app with lots of java jars in it that are dependencies. I want to know if the is a best practice fro including these Java jars in my gem.

I am going to be using a private gem repo so I do not need to worry about the jars not playing nice with java because. this will be for users running jruby only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to put all the JARs inside the gem, if there is no reason to separate the JARs and the gem. (After all, the reason to do so is to allow other gems to depend on the JARs.)

The gem should bail if `JRUBY_VERSION` is not defined anyway, just in case your future self tries to shoot herself in the foot.

Comment: Surely the reason to separate JARs from the gem is to 1) avoid creating unnecessarily large gems, and 2) allowing gems that depend on different but compatible versions of a jar (e.g. two gems depend on some-jar-1.0.1 and some-jar-1.0.2; execution only pulls in some-jar-1.0.2)